# Weird behaviour in MATLAB regarding eval()

Tags: matlab

Consider the following code

```
x = zeros(3,3);
eval(str3)
g = @(x) eval(str3)
g(x)
g(zeros(3,3))
```

MATLAB will evaluate `eval(str3)` as intended, but complain about the other two claiming they are `Undefined function for input arguments of type 'double'`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I can understand why Matlab throws an error. `str3` is undefined in your example but from your description, I can make that `str3` was defined in your workspace and contained a string. At line 3, you made a function that is independent of `x` that evaluates whatever `str3` was before you executed line 3, every time `g` is called. I think your line 3 does not reflect what you intended.

I think what you try to do is something along the lines:

```
    g = @(x) eval(x);
    g('x = zeros(3,3)')
```

But you haven't described what you aimed to achieve. Please provide more details.